# Cannot Connect to Server Instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Below is the screen shot of the error i am getting while connecting to the SQL Server instance on my system.

1. how can i fix this ?
2. copying the databases after re-installing the sql server would work ?

[image: Screen Shot of Error]

[image: Screen shot of dialog box just before clicking connect]

[image]

Comment: 99% of the time this is because your connection string is pointing to the wrong server or your box can't access it. Impossible to answer without knowing your network.

Comment: are you making a connection remotely?

Comment: not using it in a project... i am directly trying to access sql server

Comment: are you trying to connect to default instance?

Comment: Can you post an image of the window before clicking on connect? I mean the window behind this error window.

Comment: Type `localhost' in Server name and try to connect.

Comment: @Ricky thanks for the input , i have posted the screen shot before clicking connect.

Comment: Have you tried it by writing `localhost` in Server name?

Comment: Typing localhost as server name is also not working!...

Comment: i think my server instance has been corrupted , is there a way to fix that .. can i get back my databes ?

Comment: Open services and check whether Sql Server(MSSQLSERVER) service is running or not.

Comment: Does your server allow remote connections as per the message in the first screen shot?

Comment: @Ricky the service has been stopped , but i am not able to start it either ..:(

Comment: So that is the problem. What error message you are getting when trying to start the service?

Comment: i have added another screen shot of the error msg i got while trying to start the service

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to the default instance of sql server on any machine you need to only use the `Machine Name` in Server Name section of sql server connection window.

If you are trying to connect to the named instance of sql server on any machine you need to only use the `Machine Name\InstanceName` in Server Name section of sql server connection window.

If this Server is residing on your local machine then you would use `.` to connect to default instance and `.\InstanceName` to connect to the named instance on your local machine.

Other variations you can use for local machine are `local`, `(local)`, `Localhost` and the actualy `MahineName`.

*Note*

Before you do anything of above just go to your   `All Programs -->  Sql Server Folder --> Configurations Tools --> Sql Server Configuration Manager`

And check there is you have Sql Server Database  Engine Installed and it is running.  As many time people only Install the client side tools (Sql Server Management Studio) and expect to your machine to connect you to a a Sql Server Instance.

If services are `stopped` just `Right Click` and `Start`. If you can find Sql Server in your services download and Install Sql Server.

Comment: i am not able to start the service with sql server configuration manager as well..with an error msg...:"the request failed or the service did not respond in a timely manner. Consult event log..... "

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need admin rights to start the service.

Go to **Start->All Programs->Acessories** Right click on **Command Prompt** and click on **run as administrator**

Now run following Command in it:

`Net start MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER2012`

Now check the status of service.

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned in this link. http://www.rapidprogramming.com/tutorial/SQL-Server-error-3417-SQL-server-service-can-not-be-started-910

Comment: The sql service won't start if either the Sql-Server folder or the data file 
folders is compressed.  If you have done so then 
uncompress them.

Answer (score 0):

Run Services.msc from the run line. And tray restarting an instance from there.